# Deploy and run nodes dynamically in CORDA

Tags: kotlin, corda

We have a use case in which we have to deploy and start a node at runtime on button click from a web page. The same way as it working in CORDA's demo bench. Can someone please point out to an example or an explanation for achieving this?

Comment: i am facing a similar use case, can you give me some information on how you ended up achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

A node is essentially a folder containing two things:

- A `node.conf` file
- A `corda.jar` file

There are other things it may need (certificates if not in dev mode) or want (`corda-webserver` if you want it to offer an API, a plugins folder with CorDapps that you want it to load), but the two items above are sufficient.

When you run `deployNodes` locally, it creates a set of node folders containing these things. "Running a node" is equivalent to running `java -jar corda.jar` on a `corda.jar` file in a folder where a valid `node.conf` file is also present.

If you can collect the parameters for a valid `node.conf` file via a front-end or auto-generate them, then all you need to do on the server is:

- Create a new folder
- Generate a `node.conf` file and save it to the folder
- Copy a `corda.jar` file to that folder
- Start a `corda.jar` process in that folder

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.. can you please point out an example of this?..does the demo bench implement it in the same way?

Comment: Yes, DemoBench does something similar. You can see the source code here: https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/release-V1/tools/demobench. If you start a node in the DemoBench, it will show the location of the node's logs in the start-up window. If you go to this folder, you'll see that each node is simply a collection of the files described above, along with some other files. The only difference is that all nodes share a corda.jar, instead of having their own.