# How to add a new node to an existing corda network?

Tags: corda, hocon

I have a use case where I need to add a new node to an existing Corda network (let's say in existing Corda network 2 nodes are running currently (A, B node) and now need to add node C to this network.

I went through following links as well but no luck: 
[Adding new node to existing corda network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992819/adding-new-node-to-existing-corda-network) 
[Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800326/couldnt-find-network-parameters-file-and-compatibility-zone-wasnt-configured-i) 
[Deploy and run nodes dynamically in CORDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664985/deploy-and-run-nodes-dynamically-in-corda)

**I tried the following approach:** 
I Added A and B nodes configurations in **deployNodes** task inside **build.gradle** and then run deployNodes tasks so A and B nodes start-up successfully now  I create new folder PartyC and inside that added **corda.jar** and **node.conf** for node C and then running the command: 
`java -jar corda.jar` 
but I am getting the following exception while running this command:

```
Exception during node startup: Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable. [errorCode=1917kd6, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/1917kd6]
```

node.conf file for new node (node C) is following:

```
devMode=true
h2Settings {
  address="localhost:12348"
}
myLegalName="O=PartyC,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="partyc:10011"
rpcSettings {
  address="partyc:10012"
  adminAddress="partyc:10013"
}
security {
  authService {
    dataSource {
      type=INMEMORY
      users=[
        {
          password=test
          permissions=[
            ALL
          ]
          user=user1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
sshd {
  port=2227
}
```

I am not able to get how should I need to add network parameters or compatibility zone inside this node.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new node to an existing network, there are 2 possible options.

Use the network [bootstrapper](https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda/net/corda/corda-tools-network-bootstrapper/4.3/) (and [docs](https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html) to manually create the required files to allow nodes to interact with each other. This is more for test networks.

Or use a network map service, an OS implementation can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service). This is more for real networks. There is also the Corda Enterprise Network Manager if you are using Corda Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

For adding new nodes in a cordapp you need add the partyC code in build.gradle file inside this section of the code

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
 directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
```

as

```
node {
        name "O=PartyC,L=Paris,C=FR"
        p2pPort 10013
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10014")
            adminAddress("localhost:10054")
        }


        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add new node in existing Corda network using shell script. You just need to configure configuration of new node in *main build.gradle* and *clients/build.gradle* file.